# Qt: list of dynamic properties set on a given QObject?

Tags: c++, qt, reflection, qt5

Using `QMetaObject` I am able to browse all properties defined at compile-time using `Q_PROPERTY` macro...

Now I would be able to browse all dynamic properties added at run-time using `setProperty()`...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the list of all dynamic properties using `QObject::dynamicPropertyNames()`. For example:

```
QList<QByteArray> dynamicProperties = object->dynamicPropertyNames();
```

To get the property value use the same `QObject::property(const char * name )` function:

```
QVariant val = object->property(name );
```